# What length of screws to use over 3/4" plywood

Tags: screws, subfloor

What length of screw should be used when screwing 3/4" plywood subfloor to the decking underneath, in preparation for a new sheet vinyl floor?

Comment: what thickness is the decking underneath ?

Comment: The thickness of the decking is 1 1/2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me and i was going to put additional underlayment down on top of the new 3/4 ply, i would use at least 2 1/2" screws and do my best to find the floor joists below. if you are using the new ply directly as underlayment i would use 1 1/2 screws to attach to decking.

Comment: We are using the new 3/4" plywood as the underlayment against the decking, so will probably use the 1 1/2" screws as you suggest. Thanks